# How to find aggregate value in days and weeks using SQL

Tags: sql

My `db` table `housing` looks like this: (`hid` is a unique primary key)

```
HOUSING
hid   post_date              sold_date              ads        inquiry
1     2017-01-01T01:00:10    2017-02-01T01:00:10    Facebook    4
2     2017-01-01T01:00:10    2017-02-01T01:00:10    Email       21
3     2017-01-01T01:00:10    2017-02-01T01:00:10    Email       2
4     2017-01-01T01:00:10    2017-02-01T01:00:10    Radio       5
5     2017-01-01T01:00:10    2017-02-01T01:00:10    Instagram   3
```

How do I find which housing `hid` took the longest to get sold, ordered from longest to shortest?total in a day and week and which `ads` had the most inquiries, ordered from longest to shortest?total in a day and week.

**What did I do?**

I tried to find the difference between two dates `post_date` and `sold_date` but I cannot iterate and compare the values. I can just find one entry, but I need them in order.

```
# SQL ATTEMPT
SELECT * FROM housing
GROUP BY `post_date ` ASC
```

Comment: Can you post the query you've tried, be it for one row or all rows.

Comment: Just updated the sql

Comment: Great. It looks like you've got a few answers now, so I won't post my thoughts just yet.

Comment: @floss . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tagged `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` because of the usability of the shared solution. We do not need to use the `database` specific solution.

Comment: @floss . . . You have a table in a database; that is the tag that should be on  the question.  If you have copies in multiple databases, then add multiple tags.  Also, make it clear in the question that you are looking either for a solution in any or all databases.

Comment: Ok, I will consider that in my next question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the enquiry by week you can try like this.

```
SELECT id, count(inquiry) as total_enquiry as  FROM housing
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK('post_date') `post_date ` ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following SQL query to get the list of hids in order of time taken to get sold:

```
SELECT hid, DATEDIFF(sold_date, post_date) as sold_time FROM housing order by sold_time DESC
```

The following SQL query fetches list of ads ordered by inquiry:

```
SELECT ad, count(*) as total from housing GROUP BY ad ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: I need to find the `count` per `ads` so that I know `email` or `facebook` etc has the highest inquiries.

Comment: @floss add **group by ads** to group by ads and to get post for day and week use **GROUP BY TO_CHAR("timestamp_field",'YYYY-MM-DD')*** & **
GROUP BY TO_CHAR("timestamp_field",'YYYY-MM')**

Comment: Updated the answer so the ads are grouped

Comment: for the `sold` time taken part, it either gives me `-1` or `0`

Comment: I updated the answer so it uses DATEDIFF function to calculate date difference. See: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-datediff-function.php

Answer (score -1):

```sql
-- Longest to sell
select hid   
    , DATEDIFF(post_date, sold_date) as 'HID_Days'
    , DATEDIFF(post_date, sold_date)/7 as 'HID_Weeks'
from housing
Order by DATEDIFF(post_date, sold_date) desc

-- Most inquiries
select ads
        , inquiry
from housing
Order by inquiry desc

-- Most inquiry by ad type
select ads
        , sum(inquiry) as 'SumInquiries'
from housing
group by ads
Order by sum(inquiry) desc
```

Comment: `Longest to sell` gives me all `0`